# Python / Add custom document properties in a pdf?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, reportlab

is there any way to add / create custom document properties in a pdf-file using some of the existing python-modules like pypdf2, reportlab, etc.?

I would like to add here a Name and Value like you can see it here:

[image]

Comment: You can easily do this [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/). See an example in the documentation [here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-low-level-interfaces.html#how-to-extend-pdf-metadata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PyPdf2` to do that:

```py
import PyPDF2


def add_custom_property(pdf_path, property_name, property_value):
    with open(pdf_path, "rb") as file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
        pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

        [pdf_writer.add_page(page) for page in pdf_reader.pages]
        pdf_writer.add_metadata(
            {
                f"/{property_name}": property_value,
                **pdf_reader.metadata,
            }
        )

        output_path = "modified_" + pdf_path
        with open(output_path, "wb") as output_file:
            pdf_writer.write(output_file)


add_custom_property("test.pdf", "institution", "stack overflow")
```